# Java keep boolean value in a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, boolean

I have a list, each object can contain child elements.
I want to iterate recursively through each element and update the element if it contains some faulty value. The doUpdate method return true if it updated element.

*The ddmUpdated parameter is false at the start*

```
boolean updateRecursive(DDMFormField dDMFormField, List<DDMFormField> dDMFormFieldList, boolean ddmUpdated){

    if(!ddmUpdated){
    ddmUpdated = doUpdate(dDMFormField);
    }else{
        doUpdate(dDMFormField);
    }

    if(!dDMFormFieldList.isEmpty()){
        for (DDMFormField fl: dDMFormFieldList){
         ddmUpdated =   updateRecursive(fl,fl.getNestedDDMFormFields(), ddmUpdated);
        }
    }
     return ddmUpdated;
}
```

In the end I would like to return with true if I did some changes on least one element of the list. I don't know why, it always return false even if the doUpdate returned back with true and the recursion continued with ddmUpdated = true.

Can anyone suggest a correct way to keep the true value?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the return value of the recursive calls in ddmUpdated. Make sure to only overwrite it if the value is true like this:

```
boolean updateRecursive(DDMFormField dDMFormField, List<DDMFormField> dDMFormFieldList, boolean ddmUpdated){

if(!ddmUpdated){
ddmUpdated = doUpdate(dDMFormField);
}else{
    doUpdate(dDMFormField);
}

if(!dDMFormFieldList.isEmpty()){
    for (DDMFormField fl: dDMFormFieldList){
     ddmUpdated =  ddmUpdated |  updateRecursive(fl,fl.getNestedDDMFormFields(), ddmUpdated);
     
    }
}
 return ddmUpdated;
```

The or operator `|` will return true if one of the arguments is true.